# internal system error on dspace 5.2

Tags: rdbms, postgresql-9.3, dspace

I am facing an internal system error while doing metadata-import. Now even I cannot create a new collection or edit the existing item.

Please see the error log:
1st error

```
2016-07-29 10:02:41,878 ERROR org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager @ SQL create Error -
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "webapp_pkey"
  Detail: Key (webapp_id)=(12) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.doInsertPostgres(DatabaseManager.java:1743)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.insert(DatabaseManager.java:711)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.create(DatabaseManager.java:476)
    at org.dspace.app.util.AbstractDSpaceWebapp.register(AbstractDSpaceWebapp.java:80)
    at org.dspace.app.util.DSpaceContextListener.contextInitialized(DSpaceContextListener.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5525)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

2nd error

```
2016-07-29 10:30:52,482 WARN  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet @ dspace@localhost:session_id=C7C8E09E87658CA1D659C4C0C5255EB0:ip_addr=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:database_error:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException\colon; ERROR\colon; duplicate key value violates unique constraint "metadatavalue_pkey"
  Detail\colon; Key (metadata_value_id)=(125069) already exists.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "metadatavalue_pkey"
  Detail: Key (metadata_value_id)=(125069) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.doInsertPostgres(DatabaseManager.java:1743)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseManager.insert(DatabaseManager.java:711)
    at org.dspace.content.MetadataValue.create(MetadataValue.java:293)
    at org.dspace.content.DSpaceObject.updateMetadata(DSpaceObject.java:256)
    at org.dspace.content.Bitstream.update(Bitstream.java:502)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.admin.EditItemServlet.processUpdateItem(EditItemServlet.java:752)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.admin.EditItemServlet.doDSPost(EditItemServlet.java:231)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.processRequest(DSpaceServlet.java:115)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.doPost(DSpaceServlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.filter.RegisteredOnlyFilter.doFilter(RegisteredOnlyFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Where the errors come from

The error is because you are violating a restriction set on the tables. Each entry needs to have a unique key, it seems that this is not the case anymore. The keys are generated by a sequence, so if you have access to the database you can reset the sequence and solve the problem.

There are some steps that you can take to resolve this. I am assuming that this is the actual error, that you do not have any weird modification that break this. But, you'll find out soon, if this doesn't solve your problem something is messing with the database in a bad way.

Both errors have this origin. Below I will describe how you can fix them. The update-sequences.sql script should fix both of them with one run. The manual way will require you to do it twice. Once for `metadatavalue` table and once for the `webapp`table. (`metadatavalue_seq`and `webapp_seq`).

In the examples I have only used the `metadatavalue`table.

## Use the update-sequences.sql script

There are two ways that I can think of, the first is to run the `update-sequences` script that you can find under [dspace/etc/postgres](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/etc/postgres/update-sequences.sql). This script will do the same thing as what I am describing below (more or less, same result anyway).

Note that the OP is using a POSTGRES database, so if you are reading this, OP, just run the postgres part if you want to do it manually, don't run the ORACLE part. You can see from your stacktrace that you are on a postgres database `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key` ;-)

## Do it manually (postgres)

First of all, connect to the database. You can use something like *pgAdmin* or just a command line *psql* to connect.

### 1) Check the last entered key in the metadatavalue table

`select metadata_value_id from metadatavalue order by metadata_value_id desc;`

This will return the highest ID in the table. Let's say that it is 475. Just scribble this down somewhere.

### 2) Check the sequence

Next case we want to look at `metadatavalue_seq`, which is the sequence responsible for generating the IDs that are used in the `metadatavalue` table.

`select last_value from metadatavalue_seq`.

Now take a look at what this returns. If this matches the ID that you found earlier (475 in this example) then everything is actually okay with the sequence and your mistake comes from somewhere else. Let's assume that the returned ID is lower than 475, say, 301. Now the next ID that is given by the sequence might already be used by another entry in the medatavalue table, and thus causing the exception to be thrown.

### 3) Fix the sequence

We can set the last_value to something else manually. Luckily you are using `postgres` and not oracle, it's a *little* more cumbersome in oracle.

`select setval('metadatavalue_seq',(newvalue),true);`

This will set the metadatavalue_seq's current value to the new value you have specified. Remember that in our case the last value was actually 475 whilst the sequence returned 301. So to fix this, we want to set the sequence to 475 (because when it calls nextval, it will return 476).

`select setval('metadatavalue_seq', 475, true);`

## Do it manually (oracle)

The idea behind the fix is the same for an oracle database as it is for a postgres database, but the needed commands are slightly different. Oracle seems to be slightly more cryptic when it throws error messages, so you'd get an error saying something like `violation of constraint 'sys_c006541'`. This means there is one more step in figuring out where the error comes from.

### 1) Find the origin of the constraint

To find out which constraint is actually being violated, you can look up the constraint in the `user_constraints`.

`select * from user_constraints where constraint_name = "SYS_c00654"`.

Let's imagine that this constraint tells us that the constraint which is being violated is the same as the OP has (primary key in `metdatavalue` table).

### 2) Check the last entered key in the metadatavalue_table

This is the same as we have done for postgres, we will check the highest ID in the table. The query for this part actually looks the same.

`select metadatavalue_id from metadatavalue order by metadatavalue_id desc;`.

Imagine again that this returns 475.

### 3) Check the sequence

This part is slightly different for people with a postgres database. To check the last value in the sequence we can run.

`select metadatavalue_seq.nextval from dual;`.

Again, we imagine that this returns 301.

### 4) Fix the sequence

At the moment, there is no *easy* way to change a sequence within an Oracle dspace database. The easiest way I have found is to just drop the sequence and create it again from the right starting point.

first we drop it:

`drop sequence metadatavalue_seq;`

And then we recreate it:

`create sequence metadatavalue_seq start with 475;`.

---

That is basically it. I added the oracle part as well just in case someone runs into a similar error but is using an oracle database.